# How power was calculated in this study

Tags: anova, effect-size, statistical-power, gpower

In this high protein study here (http://www.mdpi.com/2072-6643/9/9/1007/htm), comparing high protein to low protein in obese sedentary women, the authors described their methods here

> An a priori power analysis was performed (G*Power v. 3.0.10, Heinrich-Heine-University Düsseldorf, Düsseldorf, Germany [24]) for an F test (repeated measures, within-between interaction factors for 2 time points) to calculate the required number of participants in each group. On the basis of a statistical power ($1–β$ err prob) of $0.80$, a moderately large effect size ($0.5$), and an overall level of significance of $0.05$, 12 subjects were required for this study."

How is this possible to get a total sample size of 12? I ran the numbers on G*power myself and got similar numbers.

These were the parameters for my calculation:

**Input**:
Effect size f                   =   0.5
            α err prob                      =   0.05
            Power (1-β err prob)            =   0.8
            Number of groups                =   2
            Number of measurements          =   2
            Corr among rep measures         =   0.5
            Nonsphericity correction ε      =   1

**Output**:
Noncentrality parameter λ       =   12.0000000
            Critical F                      =   4.9646027
            Numerator df                    =   1.0000000
            Denominator df                  =   10.0000000
            Total sample size               =   12
            Actual power                    =   0.8764178

Is this analysis wrong, and was this study with an actual n=23 statistically underpowered?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a few more details about G*Power or as a minimum the full reference [24] from the study you quote.

Comment: Is your issue that you are surprised that the number can be as small/large as 12?

Comment: @user77876 that's odd, are you unable to see the high-protein study I linked?
In any case, here's the reference about G*power, it's considered to be one of the easiest power calculators around. What I'm trying to know is, is this study powered enough?

Comment: @mdewey yes, that's also another thing I'm wondering

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17695343

Comment: @user177098 I can see the study you've linked, but your question will have a better chance of being answered if people don't have to track down the information they need. Besides being easier to answer, a more complete question is also better able to stand the test of time and avoid issues such as link rot.